# Which HTML5-element should be used for off-canvas panels?

Tags: html, panel

I have a few off-canvas panels which will appear animated from the left on click of a toggle. While the element `<aside>` is related to the content which element should be used for off-canvas or off-screen panels? The off-screen panels are not related to the content, e.g. a feedback-panel.

Comment: The element you use depends on the semantic meaning of the content, not on how you make it appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `<dialog>` is the element you are looking for:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog

Comment: That would make sense for a feedback panel. But what about a panel without a form and not related to the content?

Comment: Why would it only make sense for a feedback panel with a form? In my interpretation, that is only one example of appropriate usage of the element. But an important note about the dialog element is that it is not considered part of the document content/flow until it's open attribute is set.